# How do I use the chdir() function to go back a directory?

Tags: c, shell

I am creating a simple shell in c, and in order to recognize the "cd" command I have to implement chdir().  I know that it takes a char* as an argument, but how to I get it to execute the equivalent of "cd .."?

Comment: What, did `chdir("..")` not work?

Comment: If I call it from a child process, will it not change in the parent process?

Comment: Why are you doing it in a child process?

Comment: Because the user is able to input multiple commands at once, which I then use fork to run each command in a child process using execvp(), but in this case I have to use chdir(). So used an if-statement to check if the command is "cd" or not. I'm assuming I wont be able to do it in a child process and will have to check if it is "cd" before I fork().  @user2357112

Comment: I fixed it thank you! @user2357112

Comment: If you put `cd` into a child process, how are you going to implement `exit`?  Note that `cd` operations such as `cd ~` and `cd ~user` require processing by the shell, whereas most alternatives do not.  See also [`chdir()` to home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493234/chdir-to-home-directory)

Comment: @user2357112 `chdir("..")` is not the correct way to implement `cd ..`, it will do the wrong thing when symlinks are involved. See the `-P` and `-L` options.

Comment: @o11c: How is its behavior wrong? It sounds like we just have different expectations.

Comment: @user2357112 My "expectations" are defined by POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html

Comment: @o11c: Hm. Looks like you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Use `chdir("..");`. It will allow you to move to the previous directory like `cd ..`

Answer (score 0):

**cd** is a built-in command in the shell; it can't be implemented as a separate program. If you want to have a program change your shell's current directory for you, you'll need to do it indirectly. You may wish to have a look at the `chdir` function in `<unistd.h>`. This changes the working directory of the current process. Also refer to this link for [reference purposes](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/389378/chdir-in-c-program).