# Why does the system call chdir() not accept pathnames starting with "~"?

Tags: c, unix

I was rebuilding the bash command `ls` using C as a unix programming book exercise and had a look at various dir functions. And I realized, that `chdir`, `opendir` and similar don't accept pathnames starting with `~` but do accept `.` or `..`
First, why? And second, is the source code of the real unix `ls` command somewhere visible? Because `ls ~` does indeed work and I am curious how this works.

Comment: The `~` is expanded by the shell.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493234/chdir-to-home-directory

Comment: "~" is replaced by bash, not evaluated by 'ls' or any other command executed. You can check by calling `echo ~`. But that means if you call your ls from bash, you will get the home directory as command line argument too

Comment: ahh thanks. Yes that makes sense because I just realized that if I pass ~ as a command line argument, it works

Comment: @Lavair: Rather if you pass the expanded value of ~ (which the shell expanded) as a command line argument.

Answer (score 2):

`~` is a shell shortcut that expands to the home directory set in `/etc/passwd` or ldap configuration. The kernel has no concept of home directory and has no idea what `~` directory is.

Comment: Note that if this were not the case, it would be impoissible to create a file whose name is (or begins with) ~.

Comment: There's much more: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html

Answer (score 0):

The `~` is expanded by the shell into the home directory.

You can look up the [shell's source code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/tilde/tilde.c) to find the expansion.

Comment: @R.. See edits.